# The New Segments do not detect traffic

Tags: google-analytics, target-audience

Goodmorning everyone.

I write because I have a problem with Google Analytics.

I created 2 new segments of traffic going up (in Italian): **Analytics> Public> Overview>** then from the "**+**" button (photo 1) then I clicked on button "**New Segment**" (photo 2) and from there I filled in the parameters (photo 3) previously set by URL Builder.

These segments should serve to control traffic from **Linkedin and Facebook ads**.

**A few months ago I had done the same procedure to control the traffic of simple Facebook posts and I never had any problems**. (on photo 1 is the green track that in fact works regularly and at 8.00 showed a visit)

The problem is that these 2 new segments doesn't work: I have verified this problem by clicking on the exact link from the ads on Facebook from different devices (just to make the example of the ads on Facebook).

I'm sure I used the link generated by URL Builder by Google for those specific ads, I also tried to create a normal post using the segment that I would normally use for ads (called on Analytics: Traffic Insertions Facebook) and clicked several times ... No way.
Does not work.

Or better .. it works only if I go to: Real Time> Overview, then I see live traffic sources, but **I'm interested in seeing them from Public> Overview.
But it does not work.**

Why? Where am I wrong?

Ps: in case the photos were not displayed, here are the links:

THANKS TO ALL

[pic 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B-SRt0GUCTSYC11uhAiDrFBQmDcJztcw)

[pic 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14U3PM7gq9pTGNhJ6mjMx5hHCfnBxxXLT)

[pic 3](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Icp3ejQFZg_yBGTyTUKfCWRzRphmM20E)

---

Images:

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5v2u.jpg)

[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYFqd.jpg)

[pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrCzv.jpg)

Comment: i'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: It's hard to evaluate your segment settings without knowing the context. Can we have a screenshot of your Acquisition -> All traffic -> Source / Medium report about these same traffic sources? You can remove actual figures, just source, medium and campaign names would be helpful to see.

Comment: It is not necessary. I discovered that I made a stupid mistake: I had inverted 2 parameters when I created the new segment.
Thanks the same for the help!